# Use of second "the" in "The Art of the Deal"?

Tags: word-usage, definite-articles

I don't know, but I always feel the use of the second *the* in Trump's book title "The Art of *the* Deal" is weird. It sounds like it's referring to a specific deal that he made. We wouldn't say "The Art of *the* War", or "The Art of *the* Movement", the second *the* totally changed the meaning of the title. So my question is:

Is that title correct?

Comment: A 'deal' is an agreement. Trump is known for his many real estate (and business) agreements or 'deals' that have brought him millions of dollars. 'The deal' is used as a generic term and signifies the prototypical deal that Trump has made. In addition, as part of a title, 'deal' could have multiple meanings; one would have to be more familiar with the book to say more.

Comment: It's not Trump's book. It was written by Tony Schwartz.  Trump just paid to have his name on the cover.

Comment: @Alan Carmack So, as a native English-speaker, which I suppose you are, do you feel the title weird? Do any other English-speakers feel it weird? After all, language/grammar is defined by those who use it.

Comment: @TongFan the title is completely natural to a native English speaker

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. I edited out the second question which is off-topic. One question per post is the guideline of Stack Exchange. Please review the edit.

Comment: To my ear, *deal* requires a determiner in your example. Maybe this has something to do with [*deal*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deal) usually being understood as a verb when used without a determiner. (NB: *Deal of the Day* sounds fine, but *this is *deal of the day* doesn't. I suspect it doesn't whenever *deal* isn't the first word of a title / headline.)

Comment: @TongFan The title is completely natural.

Comment: +1 Nice grammar question. Hope you get a good answer. This is about countable and uncountable nouns and the generic use of the definite article. Notice that *war* and *movement* are both used in their uncountable senses in the titles you mention. There is no comparable uncountable sense of *deal*.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the use of the first *the* ('the art'). Does it bother you? Why or why not? How does its usage compare to/differ from the second 'the'? And yes I am a native speaker (of American English); are you a native speaker? I ask because most  native speakers have never heard of generic noun phrases, just like we've never heard of first conditional, second conditional, etc.

Comment: @Araucaria I think you may be right. Deal is a countable noun with no uncountable meaning, so it has to come with an "a" or "the." Searching the web, I found many examples of "the deal" used in phrases of indefinite sense. For example, a blog from Harvard Law School says "5 Tips for Closing the Deal." So, I guess that could be it! Thank you, Araucaria !

Comment: @AlanCarmack ~It's a linguistics thing mainly, but efl too, I suppose.

Comment: @Lawrence You're right, it's weird if there is no a "the" when used inside a sentence, because it nicely falls within the Law of Araucaria, which says that "deal" is a countable noun so it has to have an article. As for Deal of the Day, hmmm...., I guess it's a question for another day. :-) Thank you.

Comment: @Ant P Alan Carmack Thank you for replying. Yes, I thought native English-speakers wouldn't feel strange, like I did. Otherwise, the book publisher wouldn't allow it, or the American public would have said something already! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Why not put your answer in the Answer section so that I can vote for it? I think it's the most possible, if not right, answer.

Comment: "The deal" identifies a "thing", vs a process.  It implies that achieving these things is the "art", and the ultimate goal, vs the process of negotiation.

Comment: Yes, but again I ask you, why don't you question the use of *the* before *art*?

Answer (score 1):

He could have said the "Art of Deals", but saying The Deal places the word in a unique category  which the Art of a Deal does not convey, nor even the Art of  Deals.  The Deal becomes a pursuit.

A similar construction in a book title might be " the Art of The Chase"  or "the Excitement of The Chase"  =  books about hunting.

Comment: That's a very good analogy, thank you. This example further examplified @Araucaria's theory/answer above that "chase" is a countable noun in this phrase, so it just has to come with an article. (Google dictionary's examples: "she was an order follower of the chase", and "he gave up the chase.")

Answer (score -3):

The publisher got it wrong.  It should read, The Art of "The Deal".  "The Art of Deals" doesn't share the same connotation and "The Art of the Deal" applies to just one deal.